# Is JSX a requirement for using React

Tags: reactjs

I have seen code that use `React.createElement`, but i find it easier to go with

```
render(){
 return(
   <div><h1>{this.state.name}</h1></div>
 )
}
```

will this cause any problem in future?

Comment: One of the benefits of using react is it's jsx ability. So no, this code is perfectly okay and will be so in the future.

Comment: React have [very good documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html), you can find your answer there, head to [React Without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need JSX to work with React. But if you use JSX, you'll need a compiler as Babel to transpile your code. In your example :

```
render(){
 return(
   <div><h1>{this.state.name}</h1></div>
 )
}
```

Will become :

```
render(){
 return React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement("h1", null, this.state.name));
}
```

You can check out Babel live code compiler to see how your code is transpiled
https://babeljs.io/repl

See also React doc for its usage without JSX: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html